# How to store function of varying type and variable parameter using standard library only

Tags: c++, queue

As the title says, I want to store different functions say `Foo(x, y)`, `Bar(a, b, c)` into a list/queue of some sort along with their arguments so that I can pop them off one by one and execute later, I want to do this with just standard library functions.

Comment: what do they return? Same type or arbitrary types? How are you going to use the result?

Comment: for my use they can all be void, I just want to execute them. But would be good to see one that supports both.

Comment: What is the *actual* problem you need to solve? Why are you trying to store objects of different types a single container? Please [edit] your question to ask about the actual problem, and then tell us your own possible solution.

Comment: Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: storing the functions is the easy part, once you know how to use the returned value you already have half the solution. If they all return `void` its much simpler

Comment: Storing functions with varying parameters... How do you intend to call them? Which parameters you want to pass when you call them (as they are varying)? What I could imagine: store e.g. `std::vector<std::function<void()>> later;` and bind the parameters in capturing lambdas: [**demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/75f3b4eb5cdcd773). (But be aware of the proper life-time of the captured variables.)

Comment: In addition to my previous comment: The life-time issue goes away if values are captured instead of references: [**demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/02bb8569940311ea)

Comment: Maybe `std::async` and `std::launch::deferred` can help.

Comment: @Scheff Thanks, I think the second one might be something I could use in my case, will give it a try

Comment: @generic_opto_guy I am not sure what they do and how to use them, but I will read up on them, Thanks.